# In nextjs . I want to block navigation and appear a confirmation window popup when trying to navigate to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router

In nextjs . I want to block navigation and appear a confirmation window popup when user trying to navigate to another page. the navigation should continue if the user click yes in the confirmation popup. If the user clicks the "no" in confirmation window , the user should stay in the current page.

There is no way in the official nextjs documentation about blocking a router.

Comment: Are you working with Next.js 13 (`app` folder) or Next.js 12 (`pages` folder)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `window.onbeforeunload` event to do that.

See an example code below

```
const ExamplePage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload = () => true;

    return () => {
      window.onbeforeunload = null;
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Example Page</h1>
      <p>This page will display a confirmation dialog when navigating away.</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExamplePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NextJS 12 or less you can have the following:

#### Stack

- NextJS 12.x
- Typescript
- Tailwind
- Some custom components, replace on your own.

The idea behind the components below is to get when the router fires the routeChangeStart and stop it immediately, then we have two ways of getting user confirmation, you can use the window.confirm() which cannot be styled, so you probably don't want that or you can trigger an async function (which is used on the example), pass a callback so you can continue the action in case the user press "Yes" and throw immediately after, if you don't do that, it will continue the route change.

BeforePopState is when you fire the go back / go forward on the router/browser.
BeforeUnload is when the user refreshes or clicks to exit the page (in this case you can only show the browser default window.

To help you understand better and implement, here is the logic I have created.

### Code examples

`/hooks/useWarnIfUnsaved`

```
import getUserConfirmation, {
  IConfirmationBody,
  IConfirmationDialogConfig,
} from "@/utils/ui/confirmationDialog"
import Router from "next/router"
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import useWarnBeforeUnload from "./useWarnBeforeUnload"

export interface TConfirmationDialog {
  body: IConfirmationBody
  config?: IConfirmationDialogConfig
}

/**
 * Asks for confirmation to leave/reload if there are unsaved changes.
 * @param {boolean} unsavedChanges Whether there are unsaved changes. Use a ref to store the value or make a comparison with current and previous values.
 * @param {TDialog} confirmationDialog [Optional] The dialog to show.
 * @returns {void}
 */
export default function useWarnIfUnsaved(
  unsavedChanges: boolean,
  confirmationDialog: TConfirmationDialog
) {
  const unsavedRef = useRef(unsavedChanges)
  // * Keep unsaved in sync with the value passed in.
  // * At the same time we want to be able to reset
  // * the trigger locally so we can move forward on the redirection
  useEffect(() => {
    unsavedRef.current = unsavedChanges
  }, [unsavedChanges])

  useWarnBeforeUnload(unsavedRef.current)

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (url: string) => {
      if (unsavedRef.current && Router.pathname !== url) {
        Router.events.emit("routeChangeError")
        getUserConfirmation(confirmationDialog.body, {
          ...confirmationDialog.config,
          callbackAfterConfirmation: () => {
            unsavedRef.current = false
            Router.replace(url)
          },
        })
        throw "Route change aborted. Ignore this error."
      }
    }

    Router.beforePopState(({ url }) => {
      if (unsavedRef.current) {
        if (Router.pathname !== url) {
          getUserConfirmation(confirmationDialog.body, {
            ...confirmationDialog.config,
            callbackAfterConfirmation: () => {
              unsavedRef.current = false
              window.history.pushState("", "", url)
            },
          })
          return false
        }
      }
      return true
    })

    // For changing in-app route.
    if (unsavedRef.current) {
      Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange)
    } else {
      Router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange)
    }
    return () => {
      Router.beforePopState(() => true)
      Router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange)
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [unsavedRef.current])
}
```

`@/utils/ui/confirmationDialog`

```
import Button from "@/components/Buttons/Button.primitive"
import DynamicIcon from "@/components/Icons/DynamicIcon"
import Text from "@/components/Typography/Text.primitive"
import { PolarisIcons } from "@/types/polarisIcons.types"
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client"
import { cn } from "../className"

export interface IConfirmationDialogConfig {
  overrideBody?: JSX.Element
  cancelButtonText?: string
  okButtonText?: string
  title?: string
  hideOkButton?: boolean
  confirmationInput?: string
  className?: string
  bodyClassName?: string
  isDeleteConfirmation?: boolean
  callbackAfterConfirmation?: () => void
  callbackAfterCancel?: () => void
}

export interface IConfirmationBody {
  icon?: PolarisIcons | JSX.Element
  title: string
  message: string
}

interface IRenderDialogProps {
  resolve: (value: { value: string } | PromiseLike<{ value: string }>) => void
  body: IConfirmationBody
  config?: IConfirmationDialogConfig
}

type TPromiseResolve = (
  value:
    | {
        value: string
      }
    | PromiseLike<{
        value: string
      }>
) => void

const renderDialog = (
  body: IConfirmationBody,
  resolve: TPromiseResolve,
  config?: IConfirmationDialogConfig
) => {
  const root = document.querySelector("body")
  if (!root) {
    console.error("No root element found.")
    return
  }
  const div = document.createElement("div")
  div.setAttribute("id", "confirmationDialogContainer")
  div.setAttribute(
    "class",
    "h-screen w-screen fixed z-50 inset-0 grid place-items-center globalConfirmationModalContainer"
  )
  root.appendChild(div)
  const container = document.getElementById("confirmationDialogContainer")
  if (container === null) {
    console.error("Container was not found.")
  }
  const dialog = createRoot(container as HTMLElement)
  return dialog.render(
    <ConfirmationDialog body={body} resolve={resolve} config={config} />
  )
}

const removeDialog = () => {
  const root = document.querySelector("body")
  if (!root) {
    console.error("No root element found.")
    return
  }
  const divs = root.querySelectorAll(".globalConfirmationModalContainer")
  divs && divs.forEach((div) => root.removeChild(div))
}

const ConfirmationDialog = ({ resolve, body, config }: IRenderDialogProps) => {
  const clickOK = () => {
    removeDialog()
    config?.callbackAfterConfirmation?.()
    resolve({ value: "true" })
  }

  const clickCancel = () => {
    removeDialog()
    config?.callbackAfterCancel?.()
    resolve({ value: "" })
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="fixed inset-0 grid h-screen w-screen place-items-center"
      style={{ zIndex: 9999 }}
    >
      <div
        className="fixed inset-0 z-0 h-screen w-screen bg-black opacity-60"
        onClick={clickCancel}
        onKeyDown={() => undefined}
        role="button"
        tabIndex={0}
      />
      <div className="dark:bg-blue-dark relative z-10 max-w-[95vw] rounded-lg bg-white shadow-lg">
        <div className="p-14">
          {config?.overrideBody ? (
            <></>
          ) : (
            <>
              <div className="flex items-center justify-between border-b border-ds-gray-300 p-6">
                <Text
                  as="p"
                  className="text-sm font-extrabold"
                  color="text-ds-primary-700 dark:text-ds-primary-200"
                >
                  {config?.title || "Confirmation"}
                </Text>
                <Button
                  variant="icon"
                  subvariant="solo"
                  onClick={clickCancel}
                  iconName={PolarisIcons.CancelMajor}
                  className="border-none !p-0"
                />
              </div>
              <div
                className={cn(
                  "flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-7 py-12",
                  config?.bodyClassName
                )}
              >
                {body.icon && (
                  <div className="mb-4 flex items-center justify-center rounded-full">
                    {typeof body.icon === "string" ? (
                      <DynamicIcon
                        iconName={body.icon as PolarisIcons}
                        width={120}
                        className="max-w-[25%] bg-ds-gray-400 dark:bg-ds-gray-700"
                      />
                    ) : (
                      body.icon
                    )}
                  </div>
                )}
                <div className="px-8 text-center">
                  <Text
                    as="h3"
                    className="mb-2 text-lg font-extrabold leading-[1.44]"
                    color="text-ds-primary-700 dark:text-ds-primary-200"
                  >
                    {body.title}
                  </Text>
                  <Text
                    as="p"
                    className="text-sm leading-[1.57] text-ds-gray-600 dark:text-ds-gray-400"
                    font="inter"
                  >
                    {body.message}
                  </Text>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center justify-end gap-3 border-t border-ds-gray-300 p-6">
                <Button
                  variant="main"
                  subvariant="outlinePrimary"
                  size="md"
                  onClick={clickCancel}
                  className="text-ds-gray-600 dark:text-ds-gray-400"
                >
                  {config?.cancelButtonText || "Cancel"}
                </Button>
                {!config?.hideOkButton && (
                  <Button
                    variant="main"
                    subvariant={
                      config?.isDeleteConfirmation ? "error" : "primary"
                    }
                    onClick={clickOK}
                    size="md"
                  >
                    {config?.okButtonText || "Ok"}
                  </Button>
                )}
              </div>
              {/* <Text
                  as="h1"
                  label="Modal Title"
                  color="text-mirage dark:text-link-water"
                >
                  {config?.title || "Confirmation"}
                </Text>
                <Text as="p">{body}</Text>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-10 flex items-center justify-center gap-3">
                <Button
                  variant="main"
                  subvariant={
                    config?.isDeleteConfirmation ? "outlinePrimary" : "primary"
                  }
                  onClick={clickCancel}
                >
                  {config?.cancelButtonText || "Cancel"}
                </Button>
                {!config?.hideOkButton && (
                  <Button
                    variant={config?.isDeleteConfirmation ? "5" : "2"}
                    onClick={clickOK}
                    className="px-8"
                  >
                    {config?.okButtonText || "Ok"}
                  </Button>
                )} 
                </div>*/}
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

/**
 *
 * @param {IConfirmationBody} body
 * @param {IConfirmationDialogConfig} config
 * @returns
 */
const getUserConfirmation = (
  body: IConfirmationBody,
  config?: IConfirmationDialogConfig
): Promise<{ value: string }> =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    renderDialog(body, resolve, config)
  })

export default getUserConfirmation
```

### Usage

```
// only one simple example
const UnsavedChangesDialog: TConfirmationDialog = {
  body: {
    icon: <svg>ICON CODE OPTIONAL</svg>,
    title: "Your title",
    message:
      "Your message",
  },
  config: {
    okButtonText: "Yes",
    cancelButtonText: "No",
    title: "Unsaved changes",
    isDeleteConfirmation: true,
    bodyClassName: "px-[15vw]",
  },
}

const hasChanges = useRef(false)
useWarnIfUnsaved(hasChanges.current, UnsavedChangesDialog)

const handleFormChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    hasChanges.current = true
    ...
}

const submitForm = (data) => {
    ...
    if (success) {
        // important to set as false when you actually submit so you can stop showing the message
        hasChanges.current = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that this might be a great answer specifically for NextJS (what I'm looking for) if you could separate the two concepts you have  here: confirm navigate away  and confirm navigate away with custom ui. 

imo the tailwind is unessecary noise